# Как натянуть многостраничный сайт на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть верстка из n количества страниц, шапку и подвал я подключил. Мне нужно все страницы сайта натянуть на WordPress. Как мне это можно реализовать?

Comment: Это не фриланс и не гугл. Вся информация есть в интернете

Comment: Ну видимо я не умею гуглить. Раз она есть в интернете, то скинь мне ифнормацию как натянуть многостраничный сайт.

Comment: В таком случае я хочу вас разочаровать

Comment: Начни с изучения термина "CMS"